# Parent and child projects maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a scenario. We are developing Selenium Page Factory automation framework for our application. Requirement is that the framework project should be independent (or parent) from test project (child project).

Once a framework is defined, it can be reused by any number of child projects.

i.e., parent should contain class related to BasePage, BaseTest, DriverManager, DriverFactory and resources like chromedriver, IEdriver etc

child project should contain application specific pages extending BasePage from framework , and test cases extending BaseTest from framework.

Child projects should be any number like app1, app2

Please suggest best maven project architecture with sample pom.xml files.

parent

```
|_src/main/java
            |_BasePage
            |_BaseTest
            |_ReadConfigOfChild
            |_DriverFactory
|_src/main/resources
            |_chromedriver.exe
            |_IEDriverServer.exe
            |_log4j2.xml
```

child

```
|_src/main/java
            |_Page1 extends BasePage
            |_Page2 extends BasePage

|_src/main/resources
            |_config.properties (URL, username, password)
|_src/test/java
            |_Tese1 extends BaseTest
            |_Test2 extends BaseTest
|_pom.xml
|_TestNgSuite.xml
```

We should be able to simply extend parent when a new child is addding without editing parent pom

```
            |-  child1

parent  ----|-  child2

            |-  child3
```

Comment: It can be done by adding the <parent>  configuration on the child modules (in the pom.xml of the child module)

Comment: @Praveen I have added parent configuration but issue comes when I am running my tests through testng.xml. and it is working fine if I ran through same testng.xml through pom.xml

When I ran testng.xml directly the resources are not identified and getting NullPointerException. But when I ran through pom.xml (maven test) then the resources are coming correctly

Comment: Can you show us the POM.xml. I guess, this scenario could be handled by creating a profile, and in the profile we can add the configuration to force download and add the references to the jars/libraries

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like what you call *parent* should rather be called *core*, and it should not be a parent, but rather a dependency of the other projects.

**Explanation**

In Maven, simply said, your parent is not a project that contains base-classes, but just a project without sources, setting common plugins, dependencies and other configuration, used by all the (child) projects (in your aggregation build).

**Edit:**

```
MyProj/pom.xml // Aggregation/Reactor - has no parent, no sources, and (usually) no resources, but lists all modules (including parent) as modules
MyProj/modules/parent/pom.xml // has no parent (or for example sonatype, if you deploy with them), no sources, but eventually some resources, no modules
MyProj/modules/parent/src/main/resources/config/checkstyle.xml
MyProj/modules/core/pom.xml // has *parent* as parent, no modules
MyProj/modules/core/src/main/java/com/myDomain/myPkg/core/BasePage.java
MyProj/modules/core/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml
MyProj/modules/ui/pom.xml // has *parent* as parent and *core* as a dependency, no modules
MyProj/modules/core/src/main/java/com/myDomain/myPkg/ui/MyUiPage.java (extends BasePage)
MyProj/modules/service/pom.xml // has *parent* as parent and *core* as a dependency, no modules
MyProj/modules/core/src/main/java/com/myDomain/myPkg/service/MyServicePage.java (extends BasePage)
```

Comment: Sorry.. did not get your answer. Can you put some example

Comment: you can see some examples in every "maven multi-module tutorial" you can find out there, or just by looking at real-world projects like the apache ones, by browsing them in the maven central repository, best done with your favorite IDE.

Comment: i added a sample directory structure